# SecurityError translating ember.js app with google translate

Tags: ember.js

I've an ember app and I'm receiving following error when someone tries to load and translate the site using Google Translate:

`Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'http://example.com/translate_c?act=url&depth=1&hl=it&ie=UTF8&prev=_…tl=it&u=http://example.com/&usg=ALkJrhg4MVmQWxS1UiuRqV_BSingGW1UDg' cannot be created in a document with origin 'http://translate.googleusercontent.com' and URL 'http://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?act=url&depth=1&hl=it&ie…tl=it&u=http://example.com/&usg=ALkJrhg4MVmQWxS1UiuRqV_BSingGW1UDg'.`

Google Translate shows a blank page because it's not able to load the site.

I've tried also with a couple of other ember site and the error is the same.
There's something I can do to solve this problem?
Thanks

I'm using
- ember v2.8.0
- ember-cli v2.8.0
- ember-data v.2.8.0

Comment: I'm not sure, but, can you have a look at this options from [the guide](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.8.0/configuring-ember/specifying-url-type/)?

Comment: I've already set locationType to `auto`